# rendering an html table by javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I got stuck at a weird point ...

```
// ticketList refers to an html table id
console.log("ticketList.rows.length before: " + ticketList.rows.length);
    for (i= 1; i < ticketList.rows.length; i++) {
        ticketList.rows[i].remove();
        console.log(`ticket ${i - 1} removed`);
    }

    // some more code which works properly

    console.log("ticketList.rows.length after: " + ticketList.rows.length);
```

Now this is the console output:

```
ticketList.rows.length before: 13
ticket 0 removed
ticket 1 removed
ticket 2 removed
ticket 3 removed
ticket 4 removed
ticket 5 removed
ticketList.rows.length after: 19
```

The initial value of 13 is correct.
**Why does it stop after 6 iterations instead of removing twelve elements as supposed?**

I tried hardcoding the stop value in the for-loop and got the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

Comment: `ticketList.rows` is live, so as you remove the rows, this value is updated and `i` refers to a different row than it did before it was removed. In this case, I would loop backwards, starting at the last row and loop to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete a row, your indexes will be off. Easiest solution is to iterate backwards.

```
for (let i = ticketList.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    ticketList.rows[i].remove();
    console.log(`ticket ${i - 1} removed`);
}
```

Also note that this is deleting all rows, if you wanted to keep the first one, just use `i > 0`;

See [Splice not working the way I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001727/splice-not-working-the-way-i-expect/36001901#36001901)